# Esp32 stop receiving data through microros

Tags: ros2, microcontroller, micro-ros

I am facing some sort of communication issue as follows....

**Problem Description:**
I am facing difficulties when attempting to run three ESP32 devices simultaneously, each connecting to a MicroROS agent and publishing twist data to three separate bots. Despite having a strong WiFi signal and utilizing the UDP4 protocol on different ports for each ESP32 device (port 8888 and others), we encounter a recurring problem. Initially, when each ESP32 device is started individually, communication runs smoothly. However, after a short period, all three ESP32 devices cease to receive data.

**Key Details:**

WiFi Signal Strength: Strong
Protocol: UDP4
Port Configuration: Each ESP32 device uses a unique port for communication

**Efforts Made:**

Ensured strong WiFi signal.
Configured each ESP32 device to use a unique port for communication.
Verified that communication functions correctly when bots are started individually.

**Code on each ESP32(changing the node and topic names as well as ports accordingly):**

```
#include <micro_ros_arduino.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <rcl/rcl.h>
#include <rcl/error_handling.h>
#include <rclc/rclc.h>
#include <rclc/executor.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/msg/twist.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/bool.h> // Include Bool message type

rcl_subscription_t subscriber_cmd_vel;
geometry_msgs__msg__Twist msg;
rcl_subscription_t subscriber_pen_down;
std_msgs__msg__Bool pen_msg;
rclc_executor_t executor;
rclc_support_t support;
rcl_allocator_t allocator;
rcl_node_t node;
rcl_timer_t timer;

Servo servo1;
Servo servo2;
Servo servo3;
Servo servo_pen;

#define servo1_pin 25
#define servo2_pin 26
#define servo3_pin 27
#define servo_pen_pin 19
#define LED_PIN LED_BUILTIN
#define RCCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){error_loop();}}
#define RCSOFTCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){}}

void error_loop(){
while(1){
digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN));
delay(100);
}
}

void cmd_vel_callback(const void * msgin)
{
const geometry_msgs__msg__Twist * msg = (const geometry_msgs__msg__Twist *)msgin;
// Your processing logic for Twist messages goes here
}

void pen_down_callback(const void * msgin)
{
const std_msgs__msg__Bool * pen_msg = (const std_msgs__msg__Bool *)msgin;
// Your processing logic for Bool messages goes here
}

void setup() {
set_microros_wifi_transports("wifi", "password", "192.168..", 8888);
// set_microros_tcp_transports("192.168.65.44", 8892);
Serial.begin(9600);
servo1.attach(servo1_pin);
servo2.attach(servo2_pin);
servo3.attach(servo3_pin);
servo_pen.attach(servo_pen_pin);
pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
delay(2000);

allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();

RCCHECK(rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator));
RCCHECK(rclc_node_init_default(&node, "subscriber_node_3", "", &support));

RCCHECK(rclc_subscription_init_default(
&subscriber_cmd_vel,
&node,
ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(geometry_msgs, msg, Twist),
"/cmd_vel/bot3"));

RCCHECK(rclc_subscription_init_default(
&subscriber_pen_down,
&node,
ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Bool),
"/pen3_down"));

RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, 2, &allocator));
RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_subscription(&executor, &subscriber_cmd_vel, &msg, &cmd_vel_callback, ON_NEW_DATA));
RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_subscription(&executor, &subscriber_pen_down, &pen_msg, &pen_down_callback, ON_NEW_DATA));
}

void loop() {
RCCHECK(rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor, RCL_MS_TO_NS(1)));

servo1.write(msg.linear.x + 90);
servo2.write(msg.linear.y + 90);
servo3.write(msg.linear.z + 90);
// Process msg_pen_down (bool) if needed
if (pen_msg.data) {
servo_pen.write(95);
} else {
servo_pen.write(90);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try if you remove all of the servo code? Would it be different? If that are the case try to use multi core / free RTOS to separate the microros and Servo code into different task / core. Other thins to try is using the auto reconnect structure as being used in the example of microros

Comment: Thanks...Please elaborate